# How to send the non-english message using python email library?

Tags: python, email

I'm using simple python script to send email. Using this this script how to send non english message.

```
import sys, smtplib
if len(sys.argv) < 4:
 print "usage: %s server fromaddr toaddr [toaddr...]" % sys.argv[0]
  sys.exit(2)
server, fromaddr, toaddrs = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3:]
message = """To: %s
From: %s
Subject: Python message

Hello,
mesage here
 """ % (', '.join(toaddrs), fromaddr)
s = smtplib.SMTP(server)
s.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, message)
print "Message successfully sent to %d recipient(s)" % len(toaddrs)
```

Comment: What does your code look like?  What sort of problems are you encountering?

Comment: I use simple smtp library to send message. while i'm trying to send non-english message it sends only scrambled characters.

Comment: I hope now i edited my question clearly

Comment: looks like there is a missing newline between headers and body...

Comment: ok, now that you corrected that.. what error message do you get? what exactly is your question?

Comment: I'm trying to send non-english message using this script. but it shows output  like this ¹¹çèìb‚»ÌÌÌÿüÿS•E~Á|

Comment: in that case you probably got your encoding wrong. you can't just put in non-ascii characters in a text part and hope it's gonna be interpreted correctly, the message needs to be encoded correctly, with corresponding headers. see the python examples that construct a message using email.mime.text.MIMEText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, you need to encode the message in base64 with  [email.encoders.encode_base64()](http://docs.python.org/library/email.encoders.html). However, you need to read up on setting the email headers right (eg: Content-Type:) else the receiver's email program won't be able to decode it.